# Php session expires

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have this codes as below to check for session expiry in php.

Here is the jquery which keep running for every 10 seconds.

```
function session_checking()
{
    $.post( "sessionCheck.php", function( data ) {
        if(data == "-1")
        {
            alert("Your session has been expired!");
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
var validateSession = setInterval(session_checking, 10000);
```

Below is my php to check the session status.

```
<?php
session_start();

if( !isset( $_SESSION['uid'] ) || time() - $_SESSION['logtime'] > 10)
{
    //expired
    echo "-1";
    session_destroy();
}
else
{
    //not expired
    echo "1";
}
?>
```

I notice that I need the jquery to keep running it. Is it possible to just do the whole check via php and eliminated the jquery?

Comment: You can update your php session every time your user visits a page. But refreshing the session in the background every 10 seconds without jQuery or a user action is impossible.

Comment: So I guess what I am doing is correct? Is there any extra security can be added here to disallow session hijacking etc.

Comment: Google "php session hijacking".

Comment: Another thing if on the pop-up I would like to add 2 option either reload the page or  redirect to login page? How is that possible?

Comment: It's not secure to store security data in a session. Store an ID in your session and link to your database :) About the pop-up, like a JavaScript pop-up?

Comment: I dont get you what do you mean dont store security data in session?  For instance for a user is it ok to store the userID in the session? I dont get your idea of linking to a database any example on this ?

Comment: Yes Thomasa about the pop-up is there any other than java script your would suggest ?